# python button does not work when image is added

Tags: python, image, python-2.7, tkinter, photoimage

When I try to add and image to the button, the program will run, but the button will be blank and you cannot click on it.  If I change `image=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:/TeDOC/OpenFolder.gif")` to `text='Open Directory` it works fine and you are able to click the button.  I have no idea why when I change it to an img, it does not work.  Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog

class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):

def __init__(self, root):

Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, root)

# options for buttons
button_opt = {'fill': Tkconstants.BOTH, 'padx': 5, 'pady': 5}

# define buttons
Tkinter.Button(self, image=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:/TeDOC/OpenFolder.gif"), command=self.askdirectory).pack(**button_opt)

# defining options for opening a directory
self.dir_opt = options = {}
options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
options['mustexist'] = False
options['parent'] = root
options['title'] = 'This is a title'


def askdirectory(self):
#Returns a selected directoryname.
return tkFileDialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)

if __name__=='__main__':
  root = Tkinter.Tk()
  TkFileDialogExample(root).pack()
  root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to define your image, using the self.image. So try:

```
self.image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:/TeDOC/OpenFolder.gif")
```

Then under your button, put:

```
Tkinter.Button(self, image=self.image, command=self.askdirectory).pack(**button_opt)
```

Comment: This is a correct solution, but it is worth mentioning in it the reason for needing to register `image` as a class attribute (i.e. because it will get garbage collected otherwise).

Answer (score 0):

You must save the image in self.

```
self.image = Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:/TeDOC/OpenFolder.gif")
Tkinter.Button(..., image=Tkinter.PhotoImage(file="C:/TeDOC/OpenFolder.gif"), ...
```

If it is deleted it will not be displayed.